# StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

Tags: android, iphone

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
```

I want to know about it.

How it can work ?

Comment: I have noticed that this piece of code makes my application run faster. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 4):

StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them. 
StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place

and more information read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html)